# What are the things that we need to put into consideration before deleting a Business Unit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit

We are planning to delete a Business Unit, but before we take this into action, I don't know what are the other things that we need to put into consideration before we delete the BU? I can't find any knowledge articles about this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it comes down to: Communication, stakeholder management, dependencies, thoroughness and at some point, of course common sense.

Here's what I can think of:

- If your Business Unit by any chance is the Parent / Enterprise BU, it's not a good idea to begin with. I am actually doubtful if it works and I wouldn't want to try. Check that.
- Anything that is inside you BU will be inaccessible / gone.
  Back it up where necessary. (content, data extensions, journey flows, images, ...)
- Everything that is configured for your BU in the backend (Sender Authentication Package, dedicated IP address, private domains) will no longer serve a purpose. Talk to SF to take those out of your contract or you might keep paying. If you've paid for the BU itself, same here. You can share IPs to other BUs via Support, you cannot do that with Sender Authentication Packages.
- Everything that goes into your business unit (integrations) will fail.
  (subscription ...) Hope that there is some documentation and reach out to the external systems to redirect / shut off their requests.
- Special note to "delayed" integrations: Unsubscriptions from your BU could fail (depending on how the process is set up) once you delete it. Be aware that people can try and unsubscribe from "old emails" that they received before the shutdown. If the service / cloudpage / data extension / entire BU targeted by unsubscription (including List-unsubscription) is gone, people will see weird error messages and maybe call support. Prepare the support team, and space out time between last send and shutdown, so the chances of that get slimmer (few people unsubscribe from 4 weeks old emails, which makes the support manageable).
- Everything that goes out of your business unit (sendouts, data exports, API calls) will stop. Thinking that through, shut them off one by one, not with a bang. inform potential recipients of exports / API calls that you are doing this. Go through Automation studio, journeys, normal sends, cloudpages...
- Everything that is NOT actually tied to your BU (All subscribers list, all contacts) will *stay*. If you by any chance can isolate contacts that were exclusively used in that BU, backup what you need archived and then delete them, or you pay their billable contacts.
- generally, if you don't already do so. pull data out of all your data views with context to that BU to a backup Data Extension each, so you don't lose the  associations for the last 6 months of historic engagement data. Specifically the _Job and potentially the _Unsubscribe data view, in case of "bu-specific unsubscription" comes to mind, but I'd do a complete swipe over them.
- If you have other users /admins , don't delete the BU right away. Phase it out, first lock the users out for some weeks and wait a bit for people screaming that they need to recover something.